# C# While loop use nTh loop

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

I have an assignment as follows,
Create a loop the reads input until 0 is used (while input != 0) and use every 5th loop to make a sum. So if there were 14 loops i add the 5th and 10th loop to eachother, and if there are 3 loops i write 0, if there where 25 loops I add the 5th, 10th, 15th, 20th, and 25th loop to eachother and display that. The only thing I can't seem to find out is how to use every 5th loop in an if statement (or any other method). It's basic but I've been wrecking my brain all day about this... please help!

(What i have so far)

```
         Console.WriteLine("Geef een getal: ");
        int invoer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int som = 0;

        while (invoer != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Geef een getal: ");
            invoer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (invoer % 5 == 0)
            {
                invoer++;
                som += invoer;

            }

            Console.WriteLine($"De some van de 5e, 10e, 15e.....is: {som}");
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried? What were your attempts? Why have they failed? This isn't a code writing service, produce an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we'll actually be able to help(without doing your work for you).

Comment: Hint: It's worth noting that a classic `for` loop (say `for(var i = 0; i<max; ++i){/*your code*/}` is simply an easier way of saying `var i=0; while (i<max}{/*your code*/ ++i;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can increment a counter with each iteration of the loop.

Then test

```
if(counter % 5 == 0)
```

In other words, if the remainder when dividing by five is zero, you're on either the 5th, 10th, 15th, etc.

`%` is the remainder operator.

```
x % y
```

returns the remainder of `x` divided by `y`.

Comment: Thanks! I've figured that out, now I just want to add each 5th input to eachother so I'm still figuring that out

Comment: You can use another variable for a running total. If you're in a 5th loop, add the input to that sum. When the loop exits, that running total is your result.

Comment: I got it! Thanks Scott, you saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

```
   Console.WriteLine("Geef een getal: ");
   int invoer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
   int som = 0;
   int i=1;
while (invoer != 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Geef een getal: ");
    invoer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (i % 5 == 0)
    {
        som += i;
    }


    Console.WriteLine($"De some van de 5e, 10e, 15e.....is: {som}");
   i++;
}
```

I'm unable to  understand your question completely . Can you please check this is satisfy your need.I want to know invoer is the key to stop the looping Iteration.